# Failed to connect the database when using sqldf in r

Tags: r, sqldf

I loaded a csv file to my R, and when I Tried to use sqldf to select some column, it always went to

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 
  'User'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my script:

```
library("RMySQL")
library(sqldf)
acs<-read.csv("getdata_data_ss06pid.csv",head = T)
sqldf("select pwgtp1 from acs where AGEP < 50")
```

Comment: can you add output of `head(acs)` to your question. Why do you need "RMySQL" ?

Comment: See `?sqldf` and read the description of the `dbname` argument, the `drv` argument and also the part two paragraphs above the References section that begins with "On MySQL..."

Answer (score 17):

It doesn't seem like you need to load the `RMySQL` library when using `sqldf`, since you have already read the data into memory, which seems to be the problem here:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df limit 6")
```

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
>         Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
>       Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type

However if `RMySQL` library is detached, `sqldf` works:

```
detach("package:RMySQL", unload=TRUE)
sqldf("select * from df limit 6")
#   time  type
# 1    1 type1
# 2    2 type1
# 3    3 type2
# 4    4 type1
# 5    5 type2
# 6    6 type1
```

Answer (score 15):

**TL;DR**

Instead of unlaoding the `RMySql` package, explicitly set the `sqldf` default driver option to `SQLite` before calling the `sqldf` function:

```
options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite")
sqldf("select * from df limit 6")
```

**Explanation**

If not explicitly defined, the `sqldf` package decides which DB driver to use as follows:

> If not specified then the "dbDriver" option is checked and if that is not
>   set then sqldf checks whether RPostgreSQL, RMySQL or RH2 is
>   loaded in that order and the driver corresponding to the first one
>   found is used. If none are loaded then "SQLite" is used. dbname=NULL
>   causes the default to be used.

In your case, `RMySql` has already been loaded and `sqldf` will try to use the MySQL DB and write into a schema called `test`. Detaching and unloading the `RMySQL` package is one option, but not necessary. As mentioned by @GaborGrothendieck in his comment, the easiest fix is to simply tell `sqldf` which DB driver to use explicitly, i.e.

```
sqldf("select * from df limit 6", drv="SQLite")
```

To not always having to add `drv="SQLite"`, you can permanently set the default driver for the session to `SQLite`:

```
options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite")
```

Comment: This seems to be the best option, especially for larger or more complex scripts, where you also might need `RMySQL` or other DB drivers.