# Failed to connect to database: Error: Plugin mysql_clear_password could not be loaded

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I'm trying to connect to MySQL Workbench using RMySQL:

```
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"), host="hostName", port = number, user = "user", password = "password",  dbname="dbname")
```

and I got an error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :
> Failed to connect to database: Error: Plugin mysql_clear_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found.

I couldn't find anything about that error in RMySQL and I don't know how to solve that problem. Anyone could help?

Comment: Is this error coming from your code or from the MySQL server itself?

Comment: Probably from code. I mean I can see it in terminal in R Studio and I don't have any other information about that except for that what I wrote above... :(

Comment: @Natalia Please check the ODBC driver is installed on your computer. May be you could check with local database first before making a connection to remote database. Also please check the following link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416714/failed-to-connect-the-database-when-using-sqldf-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

Set system environment variable `LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN = Y`:

[image]

Comment: You are a true legend!